# How to get Series Name Based on Selection in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to get the Series Name based on what is selected in the Highcharts graph but the label does not display the series name.

Here is the link to the code I have been working on: http://jsfiddle.net/ktjno528/

```
$(function () {
    // create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            events: {
                redraw: function () {
                    var label = this.renderer.label(this.series.name, 100, 120)
                        .attr({
                            fill: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
                            padding: 10,
                            r: 5,
                            zIndex: 8
                        })
                        .css({
                            color: '#FFFFFF'
                        })
                        .add();

                    setTimeout(function () {
                        label.fadeOut();
                    }, 1000);

                }
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        series: [{name:'S1',
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });


    // activate the button
    $('#button').click(function () {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        chart.addSeries({name:'S2',
            data: [216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5]
        });

        $('#button').unbind('click');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access `this.series.name`, which returns nothing because `this.series` is an array of series. So you may want to use `this.series[0].name` or `this.series[1].name` depending on which series name you want to display.

See you [updated JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ktjno528/1/).

Comment: What do you mean by "what is selected"? I don't see where you are selecting anything.  What is your overall goal here?

Comment: @jlbriggs I agree, I don't understand what he is talking about. You should comment his post instead of my answer :)

Comment: I am selecting the series name in the graph, so when I select "S1" , I want that to be displayed in the label and when I select "S2" I want S2 to be displayed in the label. I know this.series[0].name but that is static and does not change depending on what I select in the graph.

Comment: @Gayatri But how do you select one of the series ? I can't see how you do that in the JSFiddle.

Comment: So after you click on "Add Series", you can see two series in the graph "S1" and "S2". Just clicking on them selects and unselects them.Does that make sense?

Comment: @Gayatri Oh, you mean showing/hiding the series by clicking on their legend ?

Comment: Exactly and that which has been selected should be reflected in the label